# BLE scan priority while streaming music [Android]

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an application that scans for BLE devices to get advertising information from them.
This works fine as long as I don't connect other devices to the phone.
For example, when I start streaming music to bluetooth headphones, I lose BLE packets during the scan, as if it had a lower priority.

Is there a possibility to set a higher priority to the BLE scan in order not to lose data?

Thanks,
Gianluca